# can not find the reason for 'name not defined' in python code

Tags: python, list, directory

Excuse the debugging question, new to coding in general. Cannot understand why my code suddenly wont run.
I have checked for typos which seems to not be my problem.

```
filepath = '/proper_noun.txt'

def pluralize(word):
  proper_nouns = [line.strip() for line in open (filepath)]
  for item in proper_nouns:                                  ### print out the list once.
    if (item==[-1]):
      break;
```

currently working in *google colab*.

At this point, I'm just trying to return the items from 'proper_nouns' into a list to get the ball rolling. Any ideas?

```
print (proper_nouns)


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-c6832e0493e8> in <module>()
----> 1 print (proper_nouns)

NameError: name 'proper_nouns' is not define
```

Thanks guys. I hope this question follows *SOF* etiquette

Comment: It'd be good if you included the actual whole stacktrace. You haven't specified which name Python thinks isn't defined, and the stacktrace would include that.

Comment: Also, when I run your code, there's no such error, so it's possible the error you're seeing is not being caused by the code you're posting. That's why the stacktrace would be helpful, since it might be pointing at different code. In addition, the line `item==[-1]` doesn't make sense, can you explain what you think that's doing? And, having a semicolon after `break;` isn't standard Python syntax; can you explain why you have that there?

Comment: My apologies, I have just included it into the main clause. Is the error referring to my file path by any chance?

Comment: That error is not coming from the code you've posted. Please post the code that's actually showing that error. The line it's specifically pointing out doesn't appear anywhere in your code that you've shown. If you're attempting to print `proper_nouns` outside of the `pluralize` function, that obviously wouldn't work because of scope, but we have no idea if that's what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: as for the loop, without it, printing out 'proper_nouns' object repeats endlessly. I thought adding the loop with the ``` item == [-1] ``` would stop the loop when it reaches the last element. Now referring to my own logic, there is no need for the 'break;'

Comment: Sorry Random Davis, it is certainly in there now. I think ive added what you have requested. Thank you for your patience

Comment: `item == [-1]` can never be true. `proper_nouns` is a list of strings, so `line` will be a string. So it can never be equal to a list containing a number.

Comment: I guess what you meant was `if item == proper_nouns[-1]:`

Comment: @user14519115 I just meant the semicolon. Also, you put `print (proper_nouns)` above the stacktrace but I have no idea how that relates to your actual code, unless you're saying you literally just ran that line on its own. If that's the case then it's a basic scoping issue.

Comment: Why doesn't the function use the `words` parameter?

Comment: Random Davis :  i fixed the issue. it was a scope related issue. Thanks for your input bud!

Comment: Hello again, Barmar. As for the loop issue, it simply didnt belong there, after removing it, the ouput remained the same. If i were to do as you've mentioned, Ill make sure to be careful next time. This is all useful to me. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working on Google Colab, my guesss is that you accidentally don't run the code from the beginning (from example if you selected the code starting from `for item in proper_nouns:` and only run the selected part, or if you split your program in different cells), and therefore proper_nouns is not defined yet.
Please make sure you run everything and tell us if that was it.

EDIT: I just thought of another option: is the line `print(proper_nouns)` in the `pluralize` function? If not, the scope of `proper_nouns` being the function, it's normal that it is not defined outside of the function. To access it from the outside, you must either declare it outside the function, or return it.

Comment: certainly checked that multiple times. I think Random Davis had a lead somewhere based on scope. " If you're attempting to print proper_nouns outside of the pluralize function, that obviously wouldn't work because of scope, but we have no idea if that's what you're actually trying to do"

Comment: OK you commented while I was redacting this same idea ^^ Glad you fixed it, keep coding and this kind of topics should become crystal clear in your mind!

Comment: Thanks bud, wish you all the best